# udp socket sendto implicit bind

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I'm looking at the udp client example here:
http://www.linuxhowtos.org/data/6/client_udp.c

snippet:

```
/* UDP client in the internet domain */
   struct sockaddr_in server, from;
   //...snipped

   sock= socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
   if (sock < 0) error("socket");

   server.sin_family = AF_INET;
   hp = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
   if (hp==0) error("Unknown host");

   bcopy((char *)hp->h_addr, 
        (char *)&server.sin_addr,
         hp->h_length);
   server.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));
   length=sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

   //... snipped       

   n=sendto(sock,buffer,
            strlen(buffer),0,(const struct sockaddr *)&server,length);
   if (n < 0) error("Sendto");
   n = recvfrom(sock,buffer,256,0,(struct sockaddr *)&from, &length);
   if (n < 0) error("recvfrom");
   //... snipped
```

I'm trying to understand how it knows where to receive the message from. I know when `sendto` is called an available port is chosen and that is embedded in the udp message and the server application can read that and reply to it.  How does the client code know to receive a message on that port?

This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48245273/2748602 indicates there is kind of an implicit bind when the `sendto` function is called. How does it work?  Is it in fact a bind with a random available port number that is as permanent as if I had called `bind` or something else? It seems there's some aspect of permanence.  Just interested in a little more detail.

Comment: The other end is probably using `recvfrom` which gives the address/port pair of the sender, and uses that for the reply.

Comment: "*Is it in fact a bind with a random available port number that is as permanent as if I had called bind*" - that is exactly what happens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There *is* an implicit bind if the socket is unbound since all packets have to carry both a source port. So the API assumes that if you didn't care enough about the port to bind your socket beforehand, then it can just bind the socket to a random port. And while unfortunately I don't know the implementation details of `sendto`, I can offer some official documentation.

For Linux, from the [udp man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/udp.7.html):

> When a UDP socket is created, its local and remote addresses are
>   unspecified.  Datagrams can be sent immediately using sendto(2) or
>   sendmsg(2) with a valid destination address  as  an  argument.   When 
>   connect(2)  is called  on  the  socket,  the default destination
>   address is set and datagrams can now be sent using send(2) or write(2)
>   without specifying a destination address.  It is still possible to
>   send to other destinations by passing an address to sendto(2) or
>   sendmsg(2).  **In order to receive packets, the socket can be bound to a
>   local address first by using bind(2). *Otherwise, the socket layer
>   will automatically assign a free local port out of the range defined
>   by /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range and bind the socket to
>   INADDR_ANY**.

For Windows, a snippet from the documentation for [Winsock 2's sendto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-sendto):

> **If the socket is unbound, unique values are assigned to the local
>   association by the system, and the socket is then marked as bound**. If
>   the socket is connected, the getsockname function can be used to
>   determine the local IP address and port associated with the socket.

Answer (score 0):

> ... there is kind of an implicit bind when the sendto function is called. How does it work? Is it in fact a bind with a random available port number that is as permanent as if I had called bind or something else?

[`man ip(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html):

```
   ip_local_port_range (since Linux 2.2)
          This file contains two integers that define the default local
          port range allocated to sockets that are not explicitly bound
          to a port number—that is, the range used for ephemeral ports.
          An ephemeral port is allocated to a socket in the following
          circumstances:

          *  the port number in a socket address is specified as 0 when calling bind(2);

          *  listen(2) is called on a stream socket that was not previously bound;

          *  connect(2) was called on a socket that was not previously bound;

          *  sendto(2) is called on a datagram socket that was not previously bound.
```

Comment: "When an ephemeral port is allocated"... is it allocated via a call to `bind`?