# Can 2 process receive UDP package from the same port?

Tags: sockets, networking, udp

I am writing a client program receiving data from a UDP server.

The client send a subscribe request to specified (ip, port) of server, and the server start sending UDP package to specified port of client. If some package is missing, the client send a request to another server requesting that package.

My questions, after I compile and run the client program, can I start another instance of the same client program?

Comment: I think it is fine. Incoming UDP package will be forwarded to 2 client process at the same time. But not for sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run several instances of the same client program.

But, You can't bind the same UDP port number for 2 different UDP socket at the same time in a host (without SO_REUSEADDR).

So those client instances should use different client UDP port numbers.
The best way to get different port numbers for clients: Let the OS allocate free port numbers for client sockets.

Usually that can be done by using port number zero, when binding the socket:

```
struct sockaddr_in addr;

memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
addr.sin_port = 0;

if (bind(sockfd, (const struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1)
{
    perror("bind failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

**edit:**

For receiving UDP broadcast, you can use socket option `SO_REUSEADDR` between `socket()` and `bind()` calls:

```
int val = 1;
if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &val, sizeof(val)) == -1)
{
    perror("setsockopt failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

struct sockaddr_in addr;

memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
addr.sin_port = htons(12345);

if (bind(sockfd, (const struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1)
{
    perror("bind failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

That way several processes can bind the same port for receiving broadcast messages. --> A broadcast message will be delivered to all 'listeners'.

Comment: Or if you just don't bind at all - why waste the effort? [The OS will automatically bind to a random port the first time you send something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54443823/udp-socket-sendto-implicit-bind)

Comment: @SKi The problem is that the server is broadcasting to multiple machines on specified port, say, 20005 for example.We can just use that port

Comment: @54138qqqq  For UDP broadcast the socket option SO_REUSEADDR may be usable. I updated the answer. I tested SO_REUSEADDR with Linux, I am not sure does that work with your OS.